# How to click on an element (html tag) in Robot Framework Selenium

Tags: html, robotframework, selenium2library

I'm trying to find an element on html tags using robot framework. I want to click on first element what ever the element is.

For example

1. Input text in the text field and then pass key enter
2. The item will show up and i want to click on first item but i cant

My Robot Code

```
Open Browser    http://www.tarad.com    chrome
Wait Until Element Is Visible    id=keyword
Input Text    id=keyword    dog
Press Key    id=keyword    \\13
Wait Until Element Is Visible    id=wrapper_body_all
Element Should Be Visible    id=wrapper_body_all
Click Element    xpath=//div[id='warpper_all']/div[id='wapper_body_all']//ul/il//img[constains(@src,'//img.trd.cm/120/120/sumpow/img-lib/spd_20140314140410_b.jpg')]
```

My HTML Tag

```
<div id="wrapper_body_all"> 
<div class="main-wrap">
    <!--start : #rightProduct-->
    <div class="section-col-right">         
        <!--start : rec_product -->
        <div class="rec_product">
        <!-- end : rec_product -->
        <div class="rec_product">
            <div class="section-products-box">
                <div class="hitproduct-body">
                    <ul class="hitproduct-list list">
                       <!--start : product-list--> 
                        <li>
                            <div class="item-border list">
                                <div class="item-image">
                                        <a href="//www.tarad.com/product/5913180" title="ลำโพงน่ารัก dog">
                                            <img src="//img.trd.cm/120/120/sumpow/img-lib/spd_20140314140410_b.jpg"
                                            alt="ลำโพงน่ารัก dog" data-pagespeed-url-hash="3676782613" 
                                            onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);">
                                        </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-details">                                          
                                    <div class="product-name">
                                        <a href="//www.tarad.com/product/5913180" title="ลำโพงน่ารัก dog">ลำโพงน่ารัก dog</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>      
                        </li>
                        <!--end : product-list-->
                        <!--start : product-list--> 
                        <li>
                            <div class="item-border list">
                                <div class="item-image">
                                    <a href="//www.tarad.com/product/6755464" title="Brewdog Magic Stone Dog - 330 ml - 5">
                                        <img src="//www.tarad.com/images/web_main/default150x150.gif" 
                                        alt="Brewdog Magic Stone Dog - 330 ml - 5" data-pagespeed-url-hash="2123596038" 
                                        onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-details">                                          
                                    <div class="product-name">
                                        <a href="//www.tarad.com/product/6755464" title="Brewdog Magic Stone Dog - 330 ml - 5">
                                            Brewdog Magic Stone Dog - 330 ml - 5</a> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <!--end : product-list-->
                        ....
                        ....
                        ....
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: strong text]

Error
[image]

Comment: Post your Robot code also?

Comment: What does "i can't" mean? Why can't you? How are you attempting to do it?

Comment: I just start learning Robot Framework and my Assignment want me to select first item when there show up  after i input text to search.but i cant select on the first item because there don't have any id to select :'(

Comment: @Goralight

`Click Element 
 xpath=//div[id='warpper_all']/div[id='wapper_body_all']//ul/il//img[constains(@src,'//img.trd.cm/120/120/sumpow/img-lib/spd_20140314140410_b.jpg')]`

Comment: @iSS.f You said you typed text - but with the HTML you've provided, there is non... What exactly do you want to click on? The webpage after clicking on the images or what exactly? I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Goralight     
`Open Browser    http://www.tarad.com    chrome
Wait Until Element Is Visible    id=keyword 
Input Text    id=keyword    dog
Press Key    id=keyword    \\13
Wait Until Element Is Visible    id=wrapper_body_all
Element Should Be Visible    id=wrapper_body_all
Click Element    xpath=//div[id='warpper_all']/div[id='wapper_body_all']//ul/il//img[constains(@src,'//img.trd.cm/120/120/sumpow/img-lib/spd_20140314140410_b.jpg')]`

Comment: @iSS.f Does it have to be the first entry in every situation? or do you want specifically the first entry which will always be something?

Comment: @Goralight 
Frist, Thank you for your patience and understanding my english it's very bad.

Actually i want to know how to select what ever first or second item but i don't know how to say :'( and i also write more about code and error in the content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138208/discussion-between-goralight-and-iss-f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be warned, this is quite a brittle Xpath, but it will do the job you're trying to achieve:

```
Open Browser    http://www.tarad.com    chrome
Wait Until Element Is Visible    id=keyword
Input Text    id=keyword    dog
Press Key    id=keyword    \\13
Wait Until Element Is Visible    id=wrapper_body_all
Element Should Be Visible    id=wrapper_body_all
Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath=(//div[@id='wrapper_body_all']/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li/div/div/a/img)[1]
Click Image    xpath=(//div[@id='wrapper_body_all']/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li/div/div/a/img)[1]
```

This Robot Code works for me, it goes to the site, then inputs "dog" to the search, and then clicks on the very first image result.
If you want to find the 2nd, 3rd, etc - change the last number. for example:

```
xpath=(//div[@id='wrapper_body_all']/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li/div/div/a/img)[5]
```

Will find the 5th result. just change where it says `[5]`. Also, in your Robot make sure it says the entire xpath I just posted. That includes the `xpath=`

Any questions please ask.

Comment: Thank you so much i can click on item that i want :)))))

Comment: @iSS.f No problem, glad I could help :) Have a great day!

Comment: I have one more questions `xpath=(//div[@id='wrapper_body_all']/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li/div/div/a/img)`
what the meaning of `[3]` or `[2]` after div ?

Comment: @iSS.f The `[3]` basically means find me the `3`rd entry. So for example, if there are 5 images, and you do `//img[3]` it will go through the HTML doc and find you the `3`rd entry. You can do this with all HTML elements. If you want to learn Xpath I recommend this: http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/xpath.html It helped me learn when I started out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sometimes you can use another element earlier or later that does find it, and then use
```

/preceding::div[1]

or

/ascending::div[1]

```
respectively
```