# Xpath in RobotFramework - element not found error

Tags: python, testing, exception, xpath, robotframework

I am using RobotFramework(new to it) to access `https://auth0.github.io/device-flow-playground/` and then click the `Get Started` button on this page.

My code:

```
open browser    https://auth0.github.io/device-flow-playground/
click button    xpath://*[@id="start-btn"]
```

But I am getting this error :

```
Button with locator 'xpath://*[@id="start-btn"]' not found.
```

Just can't seem to figure out what is wrong here when the xpath is given correctly. Any pointers please?

Comment: I dont know much about robot framework but it isnt a button (div it is) that you want to click.  In that case, wont "click element" help? See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829198/how-to-click-on-an-element-html-tag-in-robot-framework-selenium) helps. Also, shouldn't the xpath have //div[@id... ?

Comment: The click element worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with RobotFramework, however looks like you are missing a delay.
You need to wait for the element you want to click to be visible first and only after that to click it.
So, your code could be something like this:

```py
Open Browser    https://auth0.github.io/device-flow-playground/
Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath://*[@id="start-btn"]
Click Element   xpath://*[@id="start-btn"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The answer is
Open Browser    https://auth0.github.io/device-flow-playground/
Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath://*[@id="start-btn"] 10s
Click Element   xpath://*[@id="start-btn"]

You can increase the wait time as you needed.
And as well as if there is multiple elements of button cross check if you add as argument as needed below

Click Element  xpath:(//*[@id="start-btn"])[1]

Argument can be changed as per your need.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, then update your answer with code explanations and improved formatting. It will help others understand.

Answer (score 0):

[Click Button](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Click%20Button) only works for button elements. What you're trying to click on is a div , so you need to use [Click element](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Click%20Element) instead:

```
Click Element   xpath://*[@id="start-btn"]
```